# Passing data from a Form to another Form using Dockstyle

Tags: c#, winforms

```
public void loadform(object Form)
{
    if (this.mainpanel.Controls.Count > 0)
        this.mainpanel.Controls.RemoveAt(0);
    Form f = Form as Form;
    f.TopLevel = false;
    f.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    this.mainpanel.Controls.Add(f);
    this.mainpanel.Tag = f;
    f.Show();
}

private void Category_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    loadform(new Category());
}
```

I've used this code above to change the interface of my dashboard's mainpanel. My question is how do I pass data to the Category Forms?

I haven't tried anything yet but I just want to pass data from the dashboard Form towards the Category Form and to the other forms that can be clicked on the dashboard just like the Category Form.

Comment: Maybe you can change your title because you cant pass data form to form using dockstyle

Comment: Forms are just objects, like any other. How do you usually get data into an object? You set a property or you call a method and pass an argument. That's how you get data into forms too, because they are just objects. Constructors are methods too.

Answer (score 0):

You can add constructor of `Category form`

```
public Category(string yourValue)
{

}
```

And the usage in other form is

```
loadform(new Category("MyValue"));
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

---

*The way your question is worded, it's about "passing data" and not about "docking a child form", so this is the way I will answer it.*

---

There are *a lot* of ways to pass the `DockStyle` value to another form as your code is attempting to do. Since you're calling `f.Show` anyway, I'd recommend that you go ahead and pass the data there. You'll also need to overload the `Show` method to take an object and then validate which kind of object is being received. Since the plan seems to be showing this form repeatedly, you'll need to make sure that the native hWnd doesn't dispose when the user clicks [X] to hide it.

[image: parent and child form]

```
public partial class CategoryForm : Form
{
    public CategoryForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    }
    public void Show(IWin32Window owner, object data)
    {
        if (owner is DashboardForm dashboard && data is SomeDataClass someDataClass)
        {
            if (!Visible)
            {
                Dock = someDataClass.DockStyle;
                Location = new Point(dashboard.Right + 10, dashboard.Top);
                base.Show(owner);
            }
            textBox1.Text += someDataClass.Text;
            Text = $"Dock = {someDataClass.DockStyle} Count = {someDataClass.Count}";
            // Clear selection
            dashboard.ActiveControl = null;
        }
    }
    protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnFormClosing(e);
        if(e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
        {
            Hide();
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}
```

On the dashboard side, since the plan seems to be showing this form repeatedly, you'll hwant to make it a member variable of the `DashboardForm` class and ensure that it disposes when the Dashboard form does,

```
public partial class DashboardForm : Form
{
    public DashboardForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        buttonSendData.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            SomeDataClass data = new SomeDataClass
            {
                Count = _count,
                Text = $"Button has been clicked {_count++} times.{Environment.NewLine}",
                DockStyle = DockStyle.Fill,
            };
            CategoryForm.Show(this, data);
        };
        Disposed += (sender, e) => CategoryForm.Dispose();
    }
    int _count = 1;
    CategoryForm CategoryForm { get; } = new CategoryForm();
}
class SomeDataClass
{
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public DockStyle DockStyle { get; set; } = DockStyle.None;
}
```